# What is this delta-winged aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification, plane-spotting

I spotted this recently. The distance and poor camera makes it really hard to determine what it is. Any help appreciated. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Could it be a kite?

Comment: It could be some kind of top secret aircraft.  Did you take this picture and if you did than where.

Comment: Is it a screenshot of a Star Wars film?

Comment: Is it a paper plane?

Comment: It's a [UFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidentified_flying_object)

Answer (score 78):

*Took a fair bit of trial and error on the very vague registration on the port wing :)*

### F-PDHV (D-Plane 1)

> The [Verhees D-Plane 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhees_D-Plane_1) is a Belgian homebuilt flying wing,
>   designed by Verhees Engineering and supplied as plans for amateur
>   construction.

Picture from below:

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.wingsovereurope.com/verhees_delta.html)</sup>

[image]

<sup>David Osborne/ Aeroprints [Source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/aeroprints/9705932877/)</sup>

Comment: great sleuth work!

Comment: Wow, that's very interesting. I saw the picture and assumed it was fighter or bomber sized!

Comment: @Dan This is often the problem with photos that have no frame of reference: You can't tell if it's something really big flying very high, or something fairly small flying very low.

Comment: @Dan And I thought it was a UFO!  (Which is was... until MikeFoxtrot identified it...)

Comment: @Dan, I was assuming the other end of the scale: somebody's toy plane or drone.

Comment: and i almost thought its a top secret aircraft and the OP of question will be in a heap of trouble soon :D

Comment: @RicoRicochet If a regular civvie can snap a photo of it in plain view, it's pretty certain that it's not a top secret aircraft. ;)

Comment: @J... in fact it wasn't an aircraft at all.  That was just swamp gas you saw.

Comment: There's a great real-life example of mistaken assumption by a very experienced witness, due to lack of frame of reference, [in the second answer here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140607015828/http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/765/have-there-been-any-credible-reports-of-unidentified-flying-objects).